# vuetify carousel: How to hide the bottom control panel

Tags: carousel, vuetify.js

I need to use v-carousel without the bottom control panel. It's useless when number of images more than 20. Is it possible to hide it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the `hide-delimiters` prop. You can find all carousel props here: [VuetifyJS API](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/carousels)

```
<v-carousel hide-delimiters>
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css:

```
.carousel .carousel__controls { display: none; }
```